# Can't remove event listener using javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Tell me please, why removeEvent is not working and click on body working after removeEventListener was called. I just make it more simple for good understanding
p - my object with properties and methods;
p.is_open - true/false property;
p.switcher - DOM element;

```
function MyClassname(){
  .......
  p.switcher.onclick = function(e){
    if(p.is_open){
      p.close();
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', p.close.bind(p));
    }else{
      p.open();
      document.body.addEventListener('click', p.close.bind(p));
    };
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
  .......
};
.......
MyClassname.prototype.close = function(){
  var p = this;
  p.is_open = false;
  p.switcher.className = 'closed';
};
MyClassname.prototype.open = function(){
  var p = this;
  p.is_open = true;
  p.switcher.className = 'open';
};
```

I can solve this task in another way, but I want to get the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to save `p.close.bind(p)` in a variable. Something like `var closeHandler = p.close.bind(p);`, inside your `function MyClassname()`. Then, you do `document.body.addEventListener('click', closeHandler);` and `document.body.addEventListener('click', closeHandler);`. Using the `.bind()` method creates a **new** function, with the same body. Therefore, it can't remove because the **new** function was never added. Everytime you run `.bind()`, it's a completelly new object. Try running `var a = function(){}; console.log(a.bind(a) === a.bind(a));` on your browser's console.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I will convert it to an answer then.

Comment: removeEventListener removes events added with addEventListener...so I don't think you can use it to remove events added some other way, such as by assigning the onclick property as you have done. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: @chiliNUT The O.P. is removing the event added to the body, through `.addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the event listener because you have to store `p.close.bind(p)` in a variable.
Something like this:

```js
function MyClassname(){
  var closeHandler = p.close.bind(p);
  .......
  p.switcher.onclick = function(e){
    if(p.is_open){
      p.close();
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', closeHandler);
    }else{
      p.open();
      document.body.addEventListener('click', closeHandler);
    };
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
  .......
};
.......
MyClassname.prototype.close = function(){
  var p = this;
  p.is_open = false;
  p.switcher.className = 'closed';
};
MyClassname.prototype.open = function(){
  var p = this;
  p.is_open = true;
  p.switcher.className = 'open';
};
```

The bit `p.close.bind(p)` wil create a **new** function with the **same** body.
It is an entirelly new object. And comparing 2 different objects returns `false`.

Partially quoting MDN about [the `.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a **new** function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value [...].

---

Here's an example:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

var handler = function(){
  console.log('click');
  //this refers to the button
  this.removeEventListener('click', handler.bind(this));
};

button.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(button));
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

As you can see, the click stays there. Here's another example:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

var handler = (function(){
  console.log('click');
  //this refers to the button
  this.removeEventListener('click', handler);
}).bind(button);

button.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Storing the result of the `.bind()` inside a variable allows you to do as you wish, and you are refering to the **same exact** object.